# Making list of pairs from the numbers

Tags: probability

Given numbers $1,2,...,10$ we need to make a list of $5$ pairs from these numbers. Pairs don't contain repeated numbers and the order of digits in the pair doesn't matter (nor does the order of pairs in the list). What is the probability that a pair with both digits $\leq 5$ would appear in our list?

Is the total number of all possible "pairing" lists $C_{10}^2 \cdot C_8^2 \cdot C_6^2 \cdot C_4^2$ ? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pairs don't contain repeated numbers'? Do you only mean that a pair cannot be of the form $(a, a)$ or that the numbers cannot repeat in the whole list?

Comment: Right, pairs of the form $(a,a)$ cannot appear and in the whole list numbers don't repeat.

Comment: I do not think your calculation is correct. It counts permutations of the pairs as well as pairs in the list. I think it'll be $\frac{10!}{2^5 \cdot 5!}$

Answer (score 1):

We can permute the $10$ digits in $10!$ ways. Let the permutations represent a list by pairing two subsequent numbers. Now, a same list can be represented by $2^5 \cdot 5!$ permutations. So, are a total of $\frac{10!}{2^5 \cdot 5!}$ such lists.

As for the case you seek, let us consider the compliment. Then, there must be at least one number $>5$ in each of the pairs. As there are only $5$ of them, there'll be only one. We can assign a pair with those numbers (as order doesn't matter) and the other number can be selected in $5!$ ways. So, the probability of such a case would be $\frac{5! \cdot 2^5 \cdot 5!}{10!}=\frac{8}{63}$.

So, the probability of the case you need would be $1-\frac{8}{63}=\frac{55}{63}$.

Comment: Side note: for the sake of computing probability, you don't need to take the "orderless" aspect into consideration (i.e., you don't need to divide by $2^5\cdot5!$).

Comment: @barakmanos His other question was to calculate the total number of lists. So, I thought it'd be best. Moreover, I think it's clearer to picture.